# Running MongoDB Globally in Google App Engine

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, package.json

Prefacing this with I am very new to GCP so please bear with me if this is an obvious fix :) I am trying to deploy a MERN application to Google App Engine. So far I was able to upload my react files with ease and everything works the way it should. The only problem is I have to run my backend on a terminal myself for the data to be fetched from MongoDB in my project in App Engine (nodemon server), in addition to the fact that even once I do this the data only appears on the computer that established that connection with the database

How do I make it so my server.js file (which establishes Mongo Connection) stays running globally so I can interact with the app on any device? I stored all my backend code in a separate file called "backend" which is inside my react app parent directory.

This is my package,json file if it helps at all:

```
{
  "name": "matchmeds-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you configured [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/mongodb-google-cloud)? I came across [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app) that might help you with this issue.

Comment: A connection pool and connection health check should be implemented here to keep the persistent connection with DB and health check to ensure the connection is alive otherwise call connection close and establish a new connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I have to push my serverside code to App Engine the same way I pushed my React code, with different yaml configs for node.js files. Thanks everyone!